# Tinkoff IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

Кто нибудь работал с tinkoff iOS SDk? Проблема вся в том что документация у них на языке Objective-C а я пишу приложения на swift, кто реализовывал оплату через тинькофф помогите

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то? "Помогите" – это не вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, документацию перевел

Answer (score 1):

Я к сожалению не работал с Tinkoff SDK, но по идеи не должно возникнуть сложностей, так как ты подключаешь через Bridge Header File и можешь использовать в Swift Style - спокойно.